# "Laplace correction" in R

Tags: r, machine-learning, probability, distributions, kullback-leibler

I am trying to understand what is the ["Laplace correction" in R](https://rdrr.io/cran/tcR/src/R/measures.R), in particular, when applied to this function:

```
kl.div(.alpha, .beta, .do.norm = NA, .laplace = 1e-12)
```

Do you know the mathematical formulation of that "Laplace correction" ? How to apply it to a distribution? Any reference in the Literature?

The only piece of information I found is the following (looks like in reference to the normalization of a distribution):

```
"normalise if needed with the given laplace correction value"
```

Comment: A little googling suggests that *all* uses of "Laplace correction" in an entropy calculation context stem from this software!  That means you likely have to contact its developers for an explanation -- or else consult the source code and hope it's sufficiently revealing.

Comment: Thanks @whuber.. it looks like the Laplace correction is used within ```check.distribution```  (you can read from here:```@param .laplace Laplace correction, Parameter to the \code{check.distribution} function.```)... The ```check.distribution``` page is in https://rdrr.io/cran/tcR/man/check.distribution.html. More info in https://rdrr.io/cran/tcR/f/vignettes/tcrvignette.Rmd, where we can read:                   ```Transform "0:100" to distribution with Laplace correction 
entropy(0:100, .laplace = 1)  # (i.e., add "1" to every value before transformation).```

Comment: If I understand correctly from https://rdrr.io/cran/tcR/f/vignettes/tcrvignette.Rmd, the Laplace correction might be ```to add "1" to every value before transformation```, i.e. to add a "1" to every bin in a discrete distribution / histogram before a "transformation"... although, I am not sure about what they mean with "transformation"... Yes, probably, better to ask something to the developers..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not familiar with that R package implementation. But here's the relevant reference:

https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Additive_smoothing

> In statistics, additive smoothing, also called Laplace smoothing or
> Lidstone smoothing, is a technique used to smooth categorical data.

> Laplace came up with this smoothing technique when he tried to
> estimate the chance that the sun will rise tomorrow. His rationale was
> that even given a large sample of days with the rising sun, we still
> can not be completely sure that the sun will still rise tomorrow
> (known as the sunrise problem).

In essence, you add some fixed value to each of the raw bin counts, prior to any normalization (getting relative frequencies summing to 1). Then, you divide with the new total count (old total count N plus all the added values). The resulting value gives smoothed relative frequencies, summing to 1.

The larger number you add to each of the bins, the more smoothed the new distribution becomes when compared to the original one.

Also, like for Laplace, this approach is useful to handle bins that have zero counts, for which we still think they should have some small, but empirically not confirmed probability. And of course, specifically for the KL divergence calculation that would otherwise end up infinite in one of the edge cases.

Comment: you nailed it!! Thanks a lot! :-) .....Btw, it would be interesting to know why the developers of R (in particular those ones of the "tcR" package) decided to call this technique as the "Laplace correction", instead of the known "additive smoothing, also called Laplace smoothing".... (I really hope that the developers of the "tcR" package - Maintainer: Vadim Nazarov, vdm.nazarov@gmail.com, from: https://rdrr.io/cran/tcR/ - used the term "Laplace correction" just as a synonym of the "additive smoothing, also called Laplace smoothing") :-) :-)

Comment: The `R` developers are not the developers of most of the packages, so please don't blame them.

Comment: @whuber, thanks for your comment...btw, no blame to anyone! There is nothing in "it would be interesting to know why" or in "I really hope that the developers of....used the term....as a synonym of..." that could be related to "blame a person". :-) :-) ....In general: I ask to learn, and not to blame the work of other people :-) :-)